# Is there a way to have user stories pass on their tags to nested tasks in Azure Dev Ops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure

I have multiple user stories under a single feature.

When I assign sprints to those user stories it passes it to any task that I create under it, but when I add a new tag to that user story it will not set the tasks underneath it to inherit that new tag.

Is there a way to have tasks that are already nested under user stories to inherit a new tag?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only add the same tags for all child work items through [Edit one or more fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/bulk-modify-work-items?view=azure-devops#edit-one-or-more-fields). You may edit it in queries and backlogs.